# Two equivalent definitions of continuity cannot contradict but gets a bit confusing with these two theorem.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, proof-explanation, product-space

This is regarding **Theorem $18.4$** and **Theorem $19.6$**   from **Topology**  by   **Munkres.**

> **Theorem 18.4:**  Let $$f:A\rightarrow X\times Y$$  be given by the equation $$f(a)=(f_1(a),f_2(a)).$$ Then $f$ is continuous iff $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous.
>
> **Theorem 19.6:**  Let $$f:A\rightarrow \prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$$ br given by $$f(a)=(f_{\alpha}(a)))_{\alpha \in J}.$$ Where $f_{\alpha}:A\rightarrow X_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha.$ Then $f$ is continuous iff $f_{\alpha}$  is continuous for each $\alpha$  *provided the product space* $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$ *is  given **product topology**.*

Now , $18.4$ clearly shows that result holds irrespective of the type of topology when the product is finite.While $19.6$  shows that the results holds only for *product topology* and not for *box topology as illustrated later by example $2$* , when we are taking arbitrary product.

Now, for $19.6$ , let us take an arbitrary **open** set from $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$ , say $U=\prod_{\alpha\in J} U_{\alpha}$ where each $U_{\alpha}$ is open in $X_{\alpha}.$ Now,$a\in f^{-1}(U) \iff a\in \bigcap_{\alpha \in J} \{f_{\alpha}^{-1}(U_{\alpha})\}.$ Now by continuity of each $f_\alpha$ we know each of $f_\alpha^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$ is open in $A$. But since arbitrary intersection of open sets may or may not be open so so the proof similar to $18.4$ does not work here. Later in the example we see that indeed the intersection ends up becoming $\Phi$ for box topology and thus unable to contain any point.

But , had we taken a closed set say, $C=\prod _{\alpha\in J}C_\alpha$ from $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$ s.t each $C_{\alpha}$ is closed in $X_{\alpha}$ containing a point $x=(x_{\alpha})_{\alpha}$, then since arbitrary intersection of closed set is again a closed set we would have $f^{-1}(C)=\bigcap_{\alpha \in J} \{f_{\alpha}^{-1}(C_{\alpha})\}$ will be another closed set in $A$.But inverse of a closed set being closed set  implies continuity. But we know our function is not continuous here. So what happened?

In fact , Continuity $\iff$ inverse image of every open set is open $\iff$  inverse of every closed set is closed.

So I'm misunderstanding some point here. Please clarify.

Thank you.

Comment: In 18.4 it must be tacitly accepted that $X\times Y$ is equipped with the product topology. If not then the statement is not true.

Comment: $f_\alpha^{-1}(U), f_\alpha^{-1}(C)$ doesn't make any sense. $f_\alpha : A\to X_\alpha$, but $U,C$ aren't subsets of $X_\alpha$.

Comment: @drhab : Yes I know that. When taking finite products , there is practically no difference between product topology  and box topology.

Comment: @Max : what? Why do $U$ , $C$ have to be subsets of $X_{\alpha}?$

Comment: When $f: X\to Y$ is any function, it only makes sense to compute $f^{-1}(C)$ when $C\subset Y$. Although sometimes you could try and compute it for $C$ not a subset of $Y$, but surely you must see that when $C\cap Y=\emptyset$ (such as in your example),$f^{-1}(C) =\emptyset$, and so the equality $f^{-1}(U) =\bigcap_{\alpha\in J}f_\alpha^{-1}(U)$ is obviously false.

Comment: You only looked at closed sets in the box topology that can be written as a product. Then the conclusion that $f$ is continuous (because it has closed preimages of these sets) cannot be made yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot more closed sets in $\prod_\alpha X_\alpha$ than those that can be written as $\prod_\alpha C_\alpha$ with $C_\alpha \subset X_\alpha$ closed. This even holds for finitely many spaces: The diagonal is closed in $X \times X$ (when $X$ is Hausdorff) but not of this form.

You've only shown $f^{-1}[C]$ closed for a (too limited) subfamily of closed subsets $C$ of the product.